# Excel autofilter issue

Tags: excel

I have 4 sheets of 10000 rows ('sheet1' and 'sheet3'), both of which use autofilter and conditional formatting applied for 4 columns, a lot.

Sheet3 has no issues and the autofilter response is instant.

**Problem:**
However, the autofilter response time on sheet1 has dropped dramatically adn it is not responding, making the file frustrating to use. Is there anyway to restore the autofilter response to instant, or at least increase it?

Comment: Turn calculation off.

Comment: Hey Jeeped, thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to iterate each time manually.

Comment: @Shalini There is an option in excel to apply manual calculation during saving worksheet. That might help. You neednt iterate manually